# Store value in variable return by execute statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

```
declare @value varchar(500)
declare @Whrcol varchar(500)
declare @Whrvalue varchar(500)
set @Whrcol='Product Cat3'
set @Whrvalue='IR DOME CAMERA'
set @value=('select [Table Name] 
             from tblProductsCatalog 
             where ['+ @Whrcol+ '] ='''+@Whrvalue+'''')
execute (@value)
```

I want to save the value return by Execute statement so that I can use in next statement
i.e.

```
execute('select * from '+@value+ ' where IsActive =1')
```

But I am getting an error.

How can I do it?

I have been trying from several hours but not able to solve.

Comment: **Please** - we can't see your screen, nor read your mind - **WHAT** error are you getting?!?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
declare @value varchar(500)
declare @Whrcol varchar(500)
declare @Whrvalue varchar(500)
set @Whrcol='Product Cat3'
set @Whrvalue='IR DOME CAMERA'
execute('select @value = [Table Name] 
             from tblProductsCatalog 
             where ['+ @Whrcol+ '] ='''+@Whrvalue+'''')
execute('select * from '+@value+ ' where IsActive =1')
```

Comment: It give error...     Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@value".

Comment: @Sanchita I have changed the last line, Try it now pls.

Answer (score 0):

use sp_executesql.

Note the change to nvarchar is needed for @value. Also I seperated the returned value instead of overwritting the @value variable.

```
declare @value nvarchar(500)
declare @Whrcol varchar(500)
declare @Whrvalue varchar(500)
declare @returnValue varchar(500)  

set @Whrcol='Product Cat3'
set @Whrvalue='IR DOME CAMERA'
set @value='select TOP 1 @returnValue = [Table Name] 
             from tblProductsCatalog 
             where ['+ @Whrcol+ '] ='''+@Whrvalue+''''
exec sp_executesql @value, N'@returnValue varchar(500) output', @returnValue output

execute('select * from '+@returnValue+ ' where IsActive =1')
```